# Google Maps Plotting location on railway track

Tags: google-maps-api-3, geolocation, gmap.net

I am working on a `GSM` based tracking device . i have successfully able to plot the approximate location on google maps using `Gmap.net` library for windows application and `google maps api` for android application.I want to mainly do the tracking of the Rail coach .with my current device i gets the approximate location near the railway track.I want to shift that Location /Maker on the near by Rail track.i need help and suggestions on how to achieve this task.please help.

Comment: Sounds like a feature request: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35820156.

Comment: Do you have the coordinates of the railway line?

Comment: @geocodezip i have coordinates of all the stations on a railway line.secondly its a hectic job but i can manually take the coordinates from railway line on google maps.

Answer (score 1):

Afaik the gmap.net library does not provide any feature around pinning tracking data, so I guess some manual work might be necessary.

The naive approach is to map your track on your own, google maps etc. is fine. I fact I've used gmap.net once itself to create exactly that.

Then all you need to do is some math (useful key word here is 'shortest path'), to locate the closest matching tracking point and use interpolation to distinguish your anticipated position on the track. You can also add some plausibility checks to speed up the whole process such as "knowing" where on your track you've already been.

I've got experience in real-time tracking for TV events and can go in deeper detail if you want.